# Architect ASP.NET MVC with Polymer

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, polymer-1.0

I have built already 3 apps using ASP.NET MVC and Polymer but I always end up with the same architectural problem.

At the moment, if I want to keep separated the MVC Views from the Polymer webcomponents I end up with a structure like this one:

```
 - wwwroot
  - bower_components (polymer)
  - elements (my components)
 - View (my views)
 - Controllers (my controllers)
```

Then, if I have to resolve a specific view, for example:
http://mydomain/home/index I will end up with something like:

```
 - Controller > Home
 - Action > Index
 - View > Index.cshtml
 - Element > paper-page-index.html
```

and from my Index.cshtml

```
<!-- import the element -->
<link rel="import" href=".../paper-page-index.html" />
<!-- render the element and pass properties -->
<paper-page-index first-name="@Model.FirstName"></paper-page-index>
```

The problem is that I have to pass each single property of my ViewModel into the custom element, which become very verbose and sometime even boring.
What should be the correct way? Each .cshtml view should be treated as a web component and stop creating web components per se and including them into my .cshtml pages? Or should I have two GET methods like Martin Fowler says:

- one GET to retrieve my view (Controller/Action/.cshtml page)
- one GET to retrieve the ViewModel from MVC

Also my presentation logic should be **only** into my Polymer elements or also into my C# ViewModels?

Any clue?

Comment: Maybe you should just ditch the MVC and use Polymer as a persentation layer with your SPA application. C# for back-end, Polymer for front-end. This would be cleaner and even more maintainable architecture. I would even suggest to store code as a two different repos (frontend, api).

Comment: Actually it is already like that, what you mean with API is the frontend (api), the APIs used to generate presentation model, not data model.
But I still want to use some features of ASP.NET MVC like ASP.NET Identity, Routing. This is why I mix the two guys together

Comment: Basically what I'm saying is: Ditch the views from MVC, use it as pure API. Remove wwwroot and Views folders altogether. In fact - start the project as API only. Or even better, use .NET Core.

Comment: @Stan I am already on asp.net core, that's why I came up with this doubt.
So you are saying, I serve Polymer as simple HTML content, then each element using iron-ajax will load its viewmodel from the APIs which will contain the presentation logic?

Comment: Yeah, than you don't mix things together. Also it gives possibility to extend/use those same apis for things like mobile applications etc. Nowadays it's the way to go.

Comment: Ok, then I can even serve the HTML content and the HTML "data" from the same endpoint/project in NET Core and have a second web api project to provide the real data.
Well you give me an alternative point of view, I'll try to get it working like that

Comment: I would not serve static HTML from .NET I would just use some simple HTTP "test" server for testing and nginx/caddy/iis/apache/whatever for production. Why would use leverage .NET if you are just serving static files.

Comment: The only issue is that we use ASP.NET Identity so all our "view" are actually protected and we have automatic redirects in case of unauthorized or unauthenticated access, which become very difficult and unsecure to manage by using only Polymer and JavaScript. This is why I was still looking at serving the HTML content via NET Core

Comment: If you really need to protect the HTML then maybe. But I don't see a scenario where HTML source code should be behind authorization. HTML source code will not hold any sensitive data in SPA architecture.

Comment: I have a similar question if you are using the polymer-cli.  The `polymer build` command doesn't lend itself well to Razor.

Answer (score 4):

At the end, I decided to architect the project in this way:

**Back-end**

- asp.net core
- controllers exposing REST methods
- secured using asp.net identity

**Front-end**

- asp.net core for "front end apis"
- standard "static pages" for Polymer
- standard "elements" structure for Polymer views

A View is provided "as is" and then it asks to the "front end" apis the corresponding presentation model. Then, it queries the HTTP REST endpoint, in case it requires data from the datastore/lucene.

This represents the "two steps views" architecture pattern of M. Fowler, explained here: https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/twoStepView.html

**Advantages**

- I can still secure the entire front-end static content using ASP.NET Identity and OAuth
- I can take advantage of Polymer build because there is not strict relationship between Polymer and Razor
- I can completely separate UI, Presentation Logic and Business Logic into 3 different areas